# Is it possible to assign a phone number to a server without a third party tool?

Tags: server, sms

I have been planning a long-term development project and a major requirement for the project is to be able to have a server receive text messages.

I know about services such as Twilio and Plivo, but I'm wondering if there's another way to create this functionality without going through a paid service.

I guess a good starter question would be:  How do Twilio and Plivo do it and is there some sort of way I can recreate this myself?

I am willing to do all the research and studying necessary to figure it out, but I'm not sure where to start.

If anyone can lead me in the right direction or give me some sort of insight on this, I would appreciate it.  Thank you.

Comment: Plivo charge like 80 cents a month for a number and incoming SMS are free. Do you really think you could do it better for less?

Comment: Is it really that inexpensive?  Also, do you happen to know if Plivo has a rate for outgoing sms?  The goal is to be able to send SMS as well and every service I see charges per message sent.

Comment: Nothing is for free in this world, and that includes outgoing SMS. For someone who is willing to do all the research you sure seem to be asking me to do most of the research for you.

Comment: For the sake of argument, asking a question on StackOverflow constitutes as research.  Anyways, thanks for your comment, I'll continue my search elsewhere.

Comment: You may think it counts as research, but the StackOverflow user guide doesnt. It says - Don't ask about... Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)

Comment: I suppose asking questions doesn't count as research then.  Believe me, this isn't the first place I've looked for answers.  Cheers.

Comment: First place I looked for Plivo rates was, wait for it, plivo.com

Comment: Right, and thank you for your input but you never really shared insight on my original thought which was "Is going through a paid service necessary?"

Comment: You could buy a burner cell phone and hard wire it to your server. Then send SMS via AT commands. Will still cost you more and won't be as good though